# InvalidateQueries not working. refetching is'nt happening. always show stale data. my component not getting re-rendered on mutations

Tags: reactjs, supabase, tanstackreact-query

i'm using supabase as backend for my e-commerce project. so if i add item to cart, it works fine and CartItems component re-rendered successfully and showing the fresh data.
But inside the cartItem component , if i tried to increase or decrease the quantity. On supabase , 'quantity' column is getting update as i click on any on two buttons to increase or decrease. But here inside the UI , quantity not getting update instantly. inshort, data is not being fetched again after mutations and  cartItems component not getting re-rendered . I'm providing code below for all of my components also service functions that are responsible for making request.
please help to resolve the issue

this function responsible for fetching cartItems.

```
export const getCartItems = async () => {
    const {data, error} = await supabase.from('cart').select('*');
    if(error) throw new Error(error.message)

    return data
}
```

this function responsible to increase item's quantity.

```
export const increaseQuantity = async (itemId, itemPrice) => {
  
  const {data:item, error: quantityUpadateError} = await supabase
  .from('cart')
  .select('quantity')
  .eq('id', itemId)
  .single()

  if(quantityUpadateError) throw new Error(quantityUpadateError.message);
  
  const increasedQuantity = item?.quantity + 1;
  const increasedTotalPrice = itemPrice * increasedQuantity ;

  const { error: quantityUpdationError } = await supabase
.from('cart')
.update({ quantity: increasedQuantity, total_price: increasedTotalPrice })
.eq('id', itemId);

if(quantityUpdationError) throw new Error(quantityUpdationError.message)
}
```

this function responsible to decrease item's quantity or to delete the row.

```
export const decreaseQuantity = async (itemId, itemPrice) => {
  
  const {data: item, error: quantityUpadateError} = await supabase
  .from('cart')
  .select('*')
  .eq('id', itemId)
  .single()

  if(quantityUpadateError) throw new Error(quantityUpadateError.message);
  
  if(item?.quantity > 1) {

    const decreasedQuantity = item?.quantity -1 ;
    const decreasedTotalPrice = item?.total_price - itemPrice ;
    
    const { error: quantityUpdationError } = await supabase
    .from('cart')
    .update({ quantity: decreasedQuantity, total_price: decreasedTotalPrice })
    .eq('id', itemId); 
    if(quantityUpdationError) throw new Error(quantityUpdationError.message)
  }else{

    const { error } = await supabase
    .from('cart')
    .delete()
    .eq('id', itemId)

    if(error) throw new Error(error.message)
  }

}
```

here is the custome hook for cartItems

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { getCartItems } from "../../services/ApiCart";

const useCart = () => {
  const { data: cartItems, isLoading: loadingCart } = useQuery({
    queryFn: getCartItems,
    queryKey: ["cart"],
  });

  return { cartItems, loadingCart };
};

export default useCart;
```

here is the custome hook to update quantity

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { decreaseQuantity, increaseQuantity } from "../../services/ApiCart"

export const useQuantity = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    function checkUpdation (item,change) {
        if(change === 'increase') increaseQuantity(item.id, item.price)
        if(change === 'decrease') decreaseQuantity(item?.id, item?.price)
    }
  const {mutate: updateQuantity, isLoading: updatingQuantity} = useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({item, changeInfo}) => checkUpdation(item, changeInfo),
    mutationKey: ['cart'],
    onSuccess: () => {
        console.log('quantity updated');

        queryClient.invalidateQueries({
            queryKey: ['cart'],
        })

    },
    onError: () => {
        // alert('Quantity can\'t update for now. Try again later ')
        console.log('quantity not updated');
    }
  })

  return {updateQuantity, updatingQuantity}

}
```

below are the cartItems and cartItem components .

```
import Button from "../../ui/Button"
import CartItem from "./CartItem"
import useCart from "./useCart"
import BackButton from "../../ui/BackButton"


const CartItems = () => {
    const {cartItems, loadingCart} = useCart()    

    if(loadingCart) return <h1 className="text-stone-400">Loading Cart Items... </h1>

    const totalCartAmount = cartItems.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.total_price, 0);
    
  return (
    <section className="w-full h-full py-[3rem] px-[1rem] border-2">
      <div className="cart-wrapper w-[90%] mx-auto rounded-md bg-white py-[3rem] px-[1rem] space-y-10 ">
        <BackButton />
      <h1 className="text-center border-b pb-4">Your Cart</h1>
        <ul className="flex flex-col gap-y-8 ">
          {cartItems.map(item => <CartItem key={item?.id} item={item} />)}
        </ul>

        <div className=" grid justify-items-end gap-y-4 py-2 px-4">
          <p className=" text-xl">Total: $<strong className="strong">{totalCartAmount}</strong></p>
          <Button 
          variation='primary'
          width='fit'

          >
            Proceed to checkout
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  )
}

export default CartItems
```

finally here is cartItem component

```
import Button from "../../ui/Button"
import { useQuantity } from "./useQuantity"

const CartItem = ({item}) => {
  const {updateQuantity, updatingQuantity} = useQuantity()

  return (
        <li className="cart-item bg-stone-100 px-3 py-2 flex md:items-center max-md:items-start  md:gap-x-4 max-md:flex-col rounded-sm max-md:gap-y-1">
          <figure className="md:w-[200px] max-md:w-full md:h-[200px] max-h-[220px] h-[210px]  rounded-md ">
            <img src={item?.image} className="w-[100%] h-[100%] aspect-square rounded-md" alt="" />
          </figure>
          <div className="flex-grow w-full">
            <div className="flex items-center  justify-between md:pr-[2rem]">
              <div className="space-y-1">
                <strong className="strong ">{item?.name}</strong>
                <p className="text-sm">Delivery at: 24th July</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <strong className="strong ">Product Price</strong>
                <p className="text-center">${item?.price}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center md:gap-x-4 ">
                <p className="space-x-2">
                  <Button 
                  width='fit'
                  variation='small'
                  onClick={() => updateQuantity({item, changeInfo:'decrease'})}
                  disabled={updatingQuantity}
                  >-</Button>
                  <span className="border-2 border-stone-200 text-lg text-stone-500 py-1 px-4">{item?.quantity}</span>
                  <Button
                  width='fit'
                  variation='small'
                  onClick={() => updateQuantity({item, changeInfo:'increase'})}
                  disabled={updatingQuantity}
                  >+
                  </Button>
                </p>
                <div>
                  <strong className="strong">Total Price:</strong>
                <p>$ <strong className="text-yellow-700 text-xl">{`${item?.total_price}`}</strong></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
  )
}

export default CartItem
```

After mutations data should be re-fetched and my compenents will be re-rendered. even data updates on supabase table on every mutation. if i do hard reload to the page, then ui changes every time not automatically on mutation .
i've tried **queryClient.invalidateQueries** , **queryClient.refetchQueries**.

not getting required results . please resolve my issue